# how to apply conditional stylesheet $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/css.css') with zend-framework

Tags: zend-framework, blueprint-css

can anyone help me with  what to do for css for IE (for blueprint css)

I have done

```
<?php $headlink = $this->headLink();        
    $headlink->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/screen.css') , 'screen, projection')
        ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/ie.css'), 'screen, projection', "IE")
        ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/print.css'));
    echo $headlink;
?>
```

and this code didn't work either

```
<?php $headlink = $this->headLink();        
    $headlink->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/screen.css') , 'screen, projection')
        ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/ie.css'), 'screen, projection', true)
        ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/blueprint/print.css'));
    echo $headlink;
?>
```

**UPDATES::**

it shoudl look like

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: please add what you're expecting and what your actual result is. Also add information about if this only happens which path etc. Read the FAQs for asking a good question please, this way you'll get your help faster and it will help you more.

Comment: as you requested it's updated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/ie.css', 'screen', 'IE');
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/ie6.css', 'screen', 'IE6');
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you mean

```
->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/ie6.css'), "screen", 'IE 6')
```

The section with `IE 6` in, can be any expression used for including IE specific stylesheets

Hope that helps.